# JSON.net Deserialize discrete element into list

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have the following JSON which is meant to define a form, but each "Section" (e.g. Training, Education), is not in an array.

What I need is for each of the top sections (e.g. Training, etc.) to be converted to a C# `Section` class, and the fields under that a `List<Field>`, etc. so that it can then be rendered.

Here is the JSON I am working with.  I have tried various ways of deserialising but none work.

```
{
  "readonly": "True",

  "Training": {
    "entity": "PNLCAND",
    "type": "standard",
    "mode": "update",
    "fields": {
      "HEADER_3": {
        "caption": "Please enter all relevant work related courses",
        "type": "header",
        "update": "",
        "mandatory": false,
        "tooltip": ""
      },
      "HEADER_5": {
        "caption": "",
        "type": "header",
        "update": "",
        "mandatory": false,
        "tooltip": ""
      },
      "HEADER_6": {
        "caption": "",
        "type": "header",
        "update": "",
        "mandatory": false,
        "tooltip": ""
      }

    }
  },
  "Education": {
    "entity": "PNLCANQUA",
    "type": "repeating",
    "mode": "update",
    "fields": {
      "Q_SUBJECT": {
        "caption": "Qualifications gained",
        "type": "string",
        "length": 40,
        "update": "Y",
        "mandatory": false,
        "tooltip": ""
      },
      "TO_DATE": {
        "caption": "Date Awarded/Expected",
        "type": "date",
        "range": {
          "start": -60,
          "end": 0
        },
        "update": "Y",
        "mandatory": false,
        "tooltip": ""
      },
      "Q_GRADE": {
        "caption": "Grade/Level",
        "type": "string",
        "length": 40,
        "update": "Y",
        "mandatory": false,
        "tooltip": ""
      },
      "Q_LOCATION": {
        "caption": "School / Colleges, Universities or Institutes of Further Education",
        "type": "string",
        "length": 40,
        "update": "Y",
        "mandatory": false,
        "tooltip": ""
      }
    },
    "values": [
      {
        "TO_DATE": "2019-08-01",
        "Q_SUBJECT": "Qual 1",
        "Q_LOCATION": "School",
        "Q_GRADE": "a",
        "UDF_6_EDU001": "C"
      },
      {
        "TO_DATE": "2019-08-01",
        "Q_SUBJECT": "Qual 2",
        "Q_LOCATION": "School",
        "Q_GRADE": "a",
        "UDF_6_EDU001": "C"
      },
      {
        "TO_DATE": "2019-08-31",
        "Q_SUBJECT": "Qual 3",
        "Q_LOCATION": "Uni",
        "UDF_6_EDU001": "U"
      }
    ]
  },

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a custom `JsonConverter` if you want to deserialize the top-level sections and the variably-named fields within them into lists.  It is possible to write the converter in a generic way which will handle both the sections and the fields.

First we need to define a model to capture the data:

```
public class Section
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Entity { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Range Range { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Update { get; set; }
    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }
}

public class Range
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a generic `JsonConverter` which will handle creating the lists.  The `T` generic parameter on the class specifies the item type to use for the list (e.g. `Section` or `Field`).  The `keyPropertyName` constructor parameter tells the converter which property on the model should be used to store the item's key from the JSON.  I added `Name` properties to both `Section` and `Field` for this purpose, so `"Name"` should be passed in both cases.

The converter works by loading the JSON into a `JObject` and iterating over its properties, excluding any whose values are not objects (so this will skip over the "readonly" property at the top level, which is obviously not a section).  The remaining property values are converted to model objects using the `ToObject<T>` method (after first setting the name on it) and added to the return list.

```
public class ObjectToListConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public string KeyPropertyName { get; set; }

    public ObjectToListConverter(string keyPropertyName)
    {
        KeyPropertyName = keyPropertyName;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<T>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Properties().Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object))
        {
            JToken item = prop.Value;
            item[KeyPropertyName] = prop.Name;
            list.Add(item.ToObject<T>(serializer));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use this converter, pass an instance for both `Section` and `Field` to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` like this:

```
List<Section> sections = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Section>>(json, 
    new ObjectToListConverter<Section>("Name"), new ObjectToListConverter<Field>("Name"));
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A4uAGk

Comment: No problem; glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Training class it looks exactly how your json structure. Then use the dapper/automapper to bind the section model object.

Comment: I want to do it as Generics. Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes. You have to do with reflection get the property name and set the value.